# Responsive ribbon-type header

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to make a ribbon type header for a website I am working on but I am struggling to get the text to adapt well to a smaller resolution.

Is there a way I can make the text responsive, or flow to a double line on smaller screens?

I have put the code into JS fiddle to show what I am using [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/ubyk67uo/)

```
h3.ribbon {
background: #c3d5d8;
margin-top: 0px !important;
margin-left: -30px;
padding-left: 20px;
color: #fff;
border-bottom: 40px solid #c3d5d8;
border-right: 20px solid #fff;
height: 0px;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 18px !important;
font-family: 'ProximaNovaThin';
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;
font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: You should look to using a pseudo element for this, as this would allow you to make the triangle at the end, with a skewX. As for further responsiveness, you may be interested in using media queries, although the pseudo element could also be made responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a skew'd pseudo element for this, allowing for the text to wrap if need be.

```css
.title {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
}
.title:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 120px;
  width: 40%;
  left: 80%;
  background: lightgray;
  transform: skewX(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">this is a long title............................a really long title! Like a super long title that should require a second line!</div>
```